# Not getting expected results from SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to grab 10 results from a table that has 16k rows.

With in this table is a row called views that gets a +1 each time an artist is viewed.
But I'm getting unexpected results only the top artist.
I have the views row indexed for speed.
I know I have to loop it, but I'm unsure how to get all 10 rows

I haven't dealt with looping or getting more than one row at a time and need help formatting it with the new mysqli

[example here with printout of array returned](http://www.thelyricsfinder.com/)

```
// Get Top Viewed Artist
$TopViewedArtist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `artists` ORDER BY  `artists`.`views` DESC LIMIT 10");
$TopViewedArtistInfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($TopViewedArtist);
$TopViewedArtist_TotalRows = mysql_num_rows($TopViewedArtist);
print_r($TopViewedArtistInfo); // the data returned from the query
```

This is the solution to display the results of the artist name in a readable format.

```
    $TopViewedArtists = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `artists` ORDER BY `artists`.`views` DESC LIMIT 10');
    while (($TopArtist = mysql_fetch_assoc($TopViewedArtists)) !== FALSE) {
    //print_r($TopArtist);
    echo $TopArtist['artist']; echo "<br>";
    }
```

This code can be change for others. but needs to be updated to mysqli

Comment: Well, `mysql_fetch_assoc` gives you one row. Did you read the PHP MySQL documentation? It explains with examples how to use this stuff.

Comment: Yeah... there's an incredible lack of info in this question. What were the expected results? What does your schema look like? "It's broken" doesn't really cut it.

Comment: On rereading, it looks like maybe you were expecting `$TopViewedArtistInfo` to include all 10 rows? That's not how the function works; you need to loop over it to get everything from the query.

Comment: Or you could use [`PDO::fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to get all 10 rows at once; given that you were to switch to PDO, which makes everything simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_query` returns a `result` resource object. Think of it as an array. The only way to read the contents of that array is to iterate through it. Think of `mysql_fetch_assoc` as the same as `each` for arrays: it returns the next row and increments the internal pointer. I think this is what you want to do:

```
<?php
// Get Top Viewed Artist
$TopViewedArtists = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `artists` ORDER BY `artists`.`views` DESC LIMIT 10');
while (($artist = mysql_fetch_assoc($TopViewedArtists)) !== FALSE) {
  print_r($artist);
}
?>
```

Keep in mind also that `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an array with multiple values. The array is supposed to contain everything you see; access the values with `$artist['artist']` (outputs `Gwen Stefani`).

May I suggest that you look into mysqli or PDO instead of the basic mysql functions? The only reason to use `mysql_` functions is if you're stuck with PHP 4 (no longer supported so nobody should still be using it) or old applications. This looks like neither, and as it also seems you have no existing experience with the interface you really ought to look into the better options.

Comment: how can I make it repeat the results in a list format, just the artist from the results

Comment: `echo '<ul>'; while (...) { echo "<li>$artist[artist]</li>"; }; echo '</ul>';`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want something like this:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `artists` ORDER BY  `artists`.`views` DESC LIMIT 10");
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q)){//this will loop 10 times presuming there are at least 10 entries in your table
  //use $r here, it represents a single row
  print_r($r);
}
```

As other people have said, you should use mysqli or pdo and not the `mysql_` functions